# Accessing NodeJS data in EJS file

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am having diffculty to access NodeJS data in script using EJS.

Here is the relevant code:
\routes\maps.js:

```
var blankDb = {
  "name" : "abcd",
  "street" : "123",
  "route" : "S Main St",
  "city" : "MyCity",
  "state" : "SC",
  "country" : "United States",
  "zip" : "29010",
};
exports.main = function(req, res){
    console.log("Request details: " + req.method);
    res.render('maps/index.ejs', {cat: 'phar', lat:34.9467, lng:-81.9275, zoom:12, records: blankDb});
};
```

\views\index.ejs:

```
var category    = <%= cat %>;
var lat         = <%= lat %>;
var lng         = <%= lng %>;
var zoom        = <%= zoom %>;
var record      = <%= records %>;
```

This gives me error for:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier  for line 14 i.e. `var record = <%= records %>;`
```

Please help!!!

Comment: Where is `records`? I don't see where you initialize it

Comment: Try removing your trailing comma in the blankDb obj.

Comment: @Салман: Please see res.render call. The last key/value

Comment: @Yousef: Removing the trailing comma doesn't work. Please note that I am unable to parse 'cat' variable as well.
Parsing any non-integer variable (string / object) throws error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: @user889252 in that case have you tried double quotes instead of single, might of seen something about an issue with single quotes somewhere.