# NodeJS & Ejs - how to access the response data in script of ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

The question I ask is mostly the same with this one: [Accessing NodeJS data in EJS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311114/accessing-nodejs-data-in-ejs-file).
After `res.render('ejs', {data: data})` 
I know we can access the data inside < body > tag of ejs by writing something like this, but can we access the data inside < script > tag?

```
<%= data %>
```

Comment: aunt add more details, and code snippets. otherwise, its hard for folks to visualize what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. In your script tag do the following:

```
<script>
// If its a string enclose within quotes "<%= data %>" 
    var data = <%= data %>
    console.log(data)
</script>
```

Comment: There should be some error in your code, this should work

Comment: it cant, i think you can have a try

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is put that into the quotes, like this:

```
<script>
  console.log('<%=data%>')
</script>
```